# regarding sink aerator sizes, is 55/64" functionally identical to 22mm (M22)

Tags: bathroom, water, faucet, sink, plumbing-fixture

regarding sink aerator sizes, is 55/64" functionally identical to 22mm (M22)? I see one advertised slightly cryptically making it look like they are the same.

Comment: 22mm is 0.2mm bigger.  Will depend on the exact size of M22.  The thread type might be different also.  Usually you only mix hole sizes for bolts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.